# Apache Camel creating Consumer component

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm newbie to Apache Camel. In hp nonstop there is a Receiver that receives events generated by event manager assume like a stream. My goal is to setup a consumer end point which receives the incoming message and process it through Camel.

Another end point I simply need to write it in logs. From my study I understood that for Consumer end point I need to create own component and configuration would be like

```
   from("myComp:receive").to("log:net.javaforge.blog.camel?level=INFO")
```

Here is my code snippet which receives message from event system.

```
 Receive receive = com.tandem.ext.guardian.Receive.getInstance();
    byte[] maxMsg = new byte[500]; // holds largest possible request 
    short errorReturn = 0;
    do { // read messages from $receive until last close 
        try {
            countRead = receive.read(maxMsg, maxMsg.length);
            String receivedMessage=new String(maxMsg, "UTF-8");
            //Here I need to handover receivedMessage to camel 

        } catch (ReceiveNoOpeners ex) {
            moreOpeners = false;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            moreOpeners = false;
        }
    } while (moreOpeners);
```

Can someone guide with some hints how to make this as a Consumer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 10'000 feet view is this:

You need to start out with implementing a component. The easiest way to get started is to extend `org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent`. The only thing you have to do is override `DefaultComponent::createEndpoint(..)`. Quite obviously what it does is create your endpoint.

So the next thing you need is to implement your endpoint. Extend `org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultEndpoint` for this.  Override at the minimum `DefaultEndpoint::createConsumer(Processor)` to create your own consumer.

Last but not least you need to implement the consumer. Again, best ist to extend `org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultConsumer`. The consumer is where your code has to go that generates your messages. Through the constructor you receive a reference to your endpoint. Use the endpoint reference to create a new Exchange, populate it and send it on its way along the route. Something along the lines of

```
Exchange ex = endpoint.createExchange(ExchangePattern.InOnly);
setMyMessageHeaders(ex.getIn(), myMessagemetaData);
setMyMessageBody(ex.getIn(), myMessage);

getAsyncProcessor().process(ex, new AsyncCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(boolean doneSync) {
        LOG.debug("Mssage was processed " + (doneSync ? "synchronously" : "asynchronously"));
    }
});
```

I recommend you pick a simple component (`DirectComponent` ?) as an example to follow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've created `MessageComponent`,`MessageEndpoint`,`MessageProducer` and `MessageConsumer'. `MessageConsumer` extends `DefaultConsumer`. 

Couldnt find a method to impement to process my message. Do I need to add it in constructor itself ?

Comment: Override the `doStart()` and `doStop()` methods of `DefaultConsumer` to start/stop your external message subscription/polling. In my case I implemented a callback method in my consumer that gets called whenever I receive an external message. In that I create headers and body and set it on a new `Exchange` as shown above and the message is sent on its way down the route.

Answer (score 0):

Herewith adding my own consumer component may help someone.

```
public class MessageConsumer extends DefaultConsumer {

private final MessageEndpoint endpoint;

private boolean moreOpeners = true;

public MessageConsumer(MessageEndpoint endpoint, Processor processor) {
    super(endpoint, processor);
    this.endpoint = endpoint;

}


 @Override
protected void doStart() throws Exception {

    int countRead=0; // number of bytes read 

    do { 
         countRead++;
            String msg = String.valueOf(countRead)+" "+System.currentTimeMillis();
            Exchange ex = endpoint.createExchange(ExchangePattern.InOnly);
            ex.getIn().setBody(msg);
            getAsyncProcessor().process(ex, new AsyncCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(boolean doneSync) {
                    log.info("Mssage was processed " + (doneSync ? "synchronously" : "asynchronously"));
                }
            });
            // This is an echo server so echo request back to requester    

    } while (moreOpeners);
}

@Override
protected void doStop() throws Exception {
    moreOpeners = false;
    log.debug("Message processor is shutdown");
}

}
```